# With winsock, how receive POST Http message from IE

Tags: c++, xmlhttprequest, winsock

i have a C++ app with function receiveNetworkData(...). This function is fully useful for download any other page on the internet. Body of this f-c is here:

```
int receiveNetworkData(int socket, string *receive_data) {
  int size, receive_size = 0;
  char buf[BUFSIZE];

  clearBuffer(buf);
  receive_data->clear();
  while (((size = recv(socket, buf, BUFSIZE-1, 0)) != 0) && (size != -1)) {
    receive_size += size;
    *receive_data += buf;
    clearBuffer(buf);
  }

  if (size == -1) return -1;
  return receive_size;
}
```

But when i try use this function to get http request from IE. The recv func is blocking the program. 
I find that IE is sending the POST request in two TCP packets. It is true but sometime IE send only one packet. Now the recv just wait for the tird packet.I do not know how recognize end of message from IE.

This is the JavaScript code for send request from IE9.

```
  http_zadost.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8001/', true);      
  http_zadost.setRequestHeader("Content-length", 5);
  http_zadost.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");  
  http_zadost.send("check");
```

Comment: i do not know what you mean. Some option of the socket?

Comment: Are you implementing an HTTP server? If you are, I'm confused by your "... fully useful for download any other page on the internet" statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All sockets are *blocking* when they are created. This means that operations like reading from  them will *block* until the call can be satisfied.

In the case of `recv`, if the socket is blocking then the function will block execution until all data requested have been received. In your case `recv` will not return until `BUFSIZE-1` bytes has been put into the buffer, or an error happens.

To make a socket non-blocking using winsock, you use the function [`ioctlsocket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) like this:

```
u_long mode = 1;
ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &mode);
```

If `mode` is non-zero the socket will be changed to non-blocking mode.

### Edit

After re-reading your question, I see that the problem is that you do not know when a request from the browsers JavaScript ends. From the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) article on the HTTP protocol:

> The request message consists of the following:
>
> - A request line
> - Headers
> - An empty line.
> - An optional message body.
>
> The request line and headers must all end with  (that is, a carriage return followed by a line feed). The empty line must consist of only  and no other whitespace.

You have to read until you get the complete header, i.e. you receive an empty line. Then you should also know if there is a message body to read (there is a non-zero "Content-length" header) and how big it is.

Note that you still need to have the socket non-blocking as noted above in my answer.

Comment: Thank you, i find tutorial about it now. I hope, that now it will be ok. http://www.win32developer.com/tutorial/winsock/winsock_tutorial_4.shtm

Comment: A have exactly same code as many examples for recv data from client, but when I try receive data from IE it's problem.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Interesting for me is that when I try donwload by recv() a google page. The download is finish when recv() return 0. But in case with IE func. recv() return size of first packet (header) and next return size of second packet (body) and go for receive third packet. But there is no third packet and recv() is blocking. I write new function witch compare Content-Length from header and body and if body is in buffer with correct length -> no more call recv(). But WHY is this problem only with IE.

Comment: @Lodhart A web-server closes the connection as soon as the response to the request has been sent, this return of `0` from `recv` means that the connection has been closed. A browser has to keep the connection open after sending the request so it can receive the response. Certain HTTP headers (like `"Connection"`) can of course change that behavior.

Comment: Oh, I see, I don't realise it. I thought that recv() just identify end of request. But like you say "return of 0 from recv means that the connection has been closed". Ok it's clear for me now, thank you for your time.